# How to add multiple images and text in SSRS table cell from SqlDB XML data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, reporting-services

In the database column name XMLdata, the value is like below. How can I display these images and text in a single cell in SSRS? Thanks in advance!!

```
<table>
    <dcomp>
        <Image>"Image1.png"</Image>
        <TextBlock>TestText1</TextBlock>
    </dcomp>
    <dcomp>
        <Image>"Image2.png"</Image>
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
    </dcomp>
    <dcomp>
        <Image></Image>
        <TextBlock>TestText2</TextBlock>
    </dcomp>
    <dcomp>
        <Image>"Image3.png"</Image>
        <TextBlock></TextBlock>
    </dcomp>
</table>
```